# Django cms text editor (CKEditor) addons

Tags: django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

Trying to get the [font addon](http://ckeditor.com/addon/font) working with the django cms text editor. I have added the addon folder to both `.../djangocms_text_ckeditor/static/djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor_plugins` and `.../djangocms_text_ckeditor/static/djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins`.

Here is what I added to my settings.py

```
#----------------------------------------------------------
#                   Text Editor
#----------------------------------------------------------
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'toolbar' : 'CMS',
    'toolbar_CMS': [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['cmsplugins', '-', 'ShowBlocks'],
        ['font']
    ],
    'extraPlugins': 'font',
}
```

The plugin doesn't show when editing any text plugins within my cms pages. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is a small problem so I would imagine you have solved this by now.  For anyone else that has come here looking for info, the 'font' in toolbar_CMS needs to be capitalized so the correct code would look like

```
#----------------------------------------------------------
#                   Text Editor
#----------------------------------------------------------
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'toolbar' : 'CMS',
    'toolbar_CMS': [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['cmsplugins', '-', 'ShowBlocks'],
        ['Font']
    ],
    'extraPlugins': 'font',
}
```